# MySQL Workbench - see all the contents of a MEDIUMTEXT column?

Tags: mysql

This is an admittedly easy question, I just dont have the background in MySQL to know this and a google search has been fruitless. I have a MySQL table with a couple of mediumtext columns. When I run a SELECT query, with MySQL Workbench, it only shows me a truncated version of the contents. How can I see the entire contents of a mediumtext column within workbench? I'm sure its just a config setting I'm missing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- *SQL Query Preference* -> [*Max. Field Value Length to Display*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html#wb-preferences-sql-editor-query-sql-execution). Default 256 bytes;
- Right click on a cell with `MEDIUMTEXT` in the result pane and choose *Open value in editor*;
- *Query* menu -> *Execute (All or selection) to text*;

Comment: This does not work in MySQL WorkBench 6.3.8 on Windows 7. I am receiving 124kb of data regardless of the Max Field Value or Open value in Editor or execute to text.

Comment: I increased the Value

"Max. query length to store in history (in bytes):"